# Python - How to get accented characters correct? (BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, character-encoding, beautifulsoup, non-ascii-characters

I've write a s python code with BeautifulSoup to get HTML but not getting how to solve accented characters correct.

The charset of the HTML is this

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

I've this python code:

```
some_text = soup_ad.find("span", { "class" : "h1_span" }).contents[0]
some_text.decode('iso-8859-1','ignore')
```

And I get this:

```
CalÃ§Ãµes
```

What I'm doing wrong here? Some clues?

Best Regards,

Comment: [Beautiful Soup uses Unicode internally](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html). From Unicode you would *encode* NOT decode.

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3? And BS 3 or 4? It's always worth mentioning in Python questions, but when you're dealing with charset/encoding questions, it's absolutely critical.

Comment: @bernie: +1. Except that you should not be `encode`-ing if your goal is to put the data into a `sqlite3` database…

Answer (score 0):

The question here is about "where" do you "get this".
If that's the output received in your terminal, it might as well be possible that your terminal expects a different encoding!

You can try this when using print:

```
import sys
outenc = sys.stdout.encoding or sys.getfilesystemencoding()
print t.decode("iso-8859-1").encode(outenc)
```

Comment: I'm outputting to an SQLite3 database. Not for the screen. Sorry for not explain that in the question.

Comment: What does the SQLite3 expect as incoming encoding? Depending on that, try to encode your string to that :)

Comment: `sqlite3` databases are UTF-8, unless you explicitly change it at runtime (`PRAMGA encoding`) or change the default at compile time. IIRC, Py3 requires that you use Unicode (`str`) for all `sqlite3` methods, and breaks if the database isn't UTF-8, while Py2 allows you to use either 8-bit (`str`) or Unicode (`unicode`), but has all kinds of problems if the database and your 8-bit strings aren't UTF-8.

Comment: Further, it's not necessary to encode for your terminal - stdout will do it for you. If Python is choosing the wrong encoding for your terminal, then you should change your locale, not change your code

Answer (score 0):

As bernie points out, BS uses Unicode internally.

For [`BS3`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Beautiful%20Soup%20Gives%20You%20Unicode,%20Dammit):

> **Beautiful Soup Gives You Unicode, Dammit**
>
> By the time your document is parsed, it has been transformed into Unicode. Beautiful Soup stores only Unicode strings in its data structures.

For [`BS4`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#making-the-soup), the docs explain a bit more clearly when this happens:

> You can pass in a string or an open filehandle… First, the document is converted to Unicode, and HTML entities are converted to Unicode characters…`

In other words, it decodes the data immediately. So, if you're getting mojibake, you have to fix it before it gets into BS, not after.

The input to the `BeautifulSoup` constructor can take 8-bit byte strings or files, and try to figure out the encoding. See [Encodings](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#encodings) for details. You can check whether it guessed right by printing out `soup.original_encoding`. If it didn't guess `ISO-8859-1` or a synonym, your only option is to make it explicit: `decode` the string before passing it in, open the file in Unicode mode with an `encoding`, etc.

The results that come out of any BS object, and anything you pass as an argument to any method, will always be UTF-8 (if they're byte strings). So, calling `decode('iso-8859-1')` on something you got out of BS is guaranteed to break stuff if it's not already broken.

And you don't want to do this anyway. As you said in a comment, "I'm outputting to an SQLite3 database." Well, sqlite3 always uses UTF-8. (You can change this with a `pragma` at runtime, or change the default at compile time, but that basically breaks the Python interface, so… don't.) And the Python interface only allows UTF-8 in Py2 `str` (and of course in Py2 `unicode`/Py3 `str`, there is no encoding.) So, if you try to encode the BS data into Latin-1 to store in the database, you're creating problems. Just store the Unicode as-is, or encode it to UTF-8 if you must (Py2 only).

If you don't want to figure all of this out, just use Unicode everywhere after the initial call to `BeautifulSoup` and you'll never go wrong.